# How to cite the same author multiples times in IEEE style?

Tags: citation-style, ieee

For example:

> According to Smith [5]...

For the second reference to the same author, would I write the following:

> [5] argues that...

Is it appropriate to begin a sentence with a bracket?  Can someone please show me the correct options for referencing the same author multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

In the IEEE style, and more generally in numeric citation styles, one only rarely writes the author names.

I'd thus rewrite the first sentence as

> According to [5] [...]

Starting a sentence with a citation may not be inappropriate but may reduce readability (this kind of issues if frequently fixed by the copy editor anyway). I'd thus rewrite your second sentence as

> In [5] it is argued that [...]